# Is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.2 valid for .NET 4.7.x projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET console project targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2.

It uses Microsoft EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.2 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.0
it fails at runtime with the following error :

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Méthode introuvable : 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IndexBuilder Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasIndex(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<System.__Canon,System.Object>>)'.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserContext`5.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<OnModelCreating>b__0(EntityTypeBuilder`1 b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.Entity[TEntity](Action`1 buildAction)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserContext`5.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext`8.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   at RTE.Technologies.SafeProtect.Common.Data.DbContext.Core.IdentityDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in D:\AzureDevops\SafeProtect.Common\SafeProtect.Common.Data\DbContext\Core\IdentityDbContext.cs:line 224
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Set[TEntity]()
   at RTE.Technologies.SafeProtect.Common.Data.DbContext.Core.IdentityDbContext.RTE.Technologies.Common.EFCoreData.Interfaces.IDbContext<RTE.Technologies.SafeProtect.Common.Data.BusinessObjects.Models.WebAdminUser>.get_DbSet() in D:\AzureDevops\SafeProtect.Common\SafeProtect.Common.Data\DbContext\Core\IdentityDbContext.cs:line 156
   at RTE.Technologies.Common.EFCoreData.Repositories.Repository`1..ctor(IDbContext`1 context)
   at RTE.Technologies.Common.EFCoreData.Repositories.DisableableWithDateTimeRepository`1..ctor(IDbContext`1 context)
   at RTE.Technologies.SafeProtect.Common.Data.DbContext.Core.IdentityDbContext.get_WebAdminUserRepository() in D:\AzureDevops\SafeProtect.Common\SafeProtect.Common.Data\DbContext\Core\IdentityDbContext.cs:line 127
   at RTE.Technologies.SafeProtect.Common.Data.DataBridge.Core.IdentityDataBridge.GetAllUsersAdminEmailByCompanyId(Int32 companyId) in D:\AzureDevops\SafeProtect.Common\SafeProtect.Common.Data\DataBridge\Core\IdentityDataBridge.WebAdminUser.cs:line 69
   at RTE.Technologies.SafeProtect.Common.DummyConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\AzureDevops\SafeProtect.Common\SafeProtect.Common.DummyConsole\Program.cs:line 45
```

I would say that I should upgrade Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore to version 3.1.2 but I can't:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

What are my options here are as I'm stuck with EF Core 3.1.2 that should be used in several projects targeting both .NET Core 3.0 and .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix 3.x and 2.x dependencies

Comment: Is it an issue with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.2 not targeting .NET Framework 4.7.x because all other related packages are?

Comment: Ah, yes, that package probably targets .net standard 2.1

Comment: Confirmed. Microsoft EntityFrameworkCore targets .net standard 2.0

Comment: The real issue is that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.2 does not support .NET Standard 2.0 like EF Core 3.1 does

Comment: Yes Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore targets are aligned with Microsoft.AspNetCore.